# How to pass and set state with ContextAPI with Typescript in React?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-state, react-typescript, react-context

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, as I've used ContextAPI outside of TS, and I think I'm implementing TS correctly. Maybe someone can shed light on what I'm doing wrong. I'm not getting any errors, but when I call the setter, nothing happens. I want to be able to dynamically open and close panels on page load of certain pages by using this prop and reset the state by passing a cleanup function to useEffect. Please let me know if there's a better way to do this.

Thanks!

My _app.tsx file:

```
import '../styles/globals.scss'
import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core/styles.css'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { ThemeProvider } from '@material-ui/core'
import { useStore }from '../store'
import type { AppProps } from 'next/app'
import theme from '../styles/theme'
import { AnimatePresence, motion } from 'framer-motion'
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
import { useCallback, useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react'
import NavBar from '../components/NavBar'
import Footer from '../components/Footer'
import MenuPanel from '../components/MenuPanel'
import { useResizeDetector } from 'react-resize-detector/build/withPolyfill'
import { Grid, useMediaQuery } from '@material-ui/core'
import Head from 'next/head'
import { UIProvider, useUIContext } from '../contexts/UIContext'

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  const isMobile = useMediaQuery('(max-width:600px)')
  const router = useRouter()
  const store = useStore(pageProps.initialReduxState)
  const { menuPanelOpen, setMenuPanelOpen, navbarOpen, setNavbarOpen } = useUIContext()

  useEffect(() => {
    if ((global.window as any).Cypress) {
      global.window.store = store
      console.log("Cypress store is running and linked to global document")
    }
  },[])

  return(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Head>
        <meta content='width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no' name='viewport' />
      </Head>
      <UIProvider>
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <Grid container flexDirection="column">
          <Grid container item flexWrap="nowrap">
            { menuPanelOpen && <MenuPanel /> }
            <Grid container item flexDirection="column" sx={{minHeight: '100vh'}}>
              { navbarOpen && <NavBar isMobile={isMobile} /> }
              <AnimatePresence exitBeforeEnter>
                <Grid container item justifyContent="center" flexGrow={1} component={motion.div} key={router.pathname} initial={{opacity: 0, y: 20}} animate={{opacity: 1, y: 0}} exit={{opacity: 0, y: -20}}>
                  <Component {...pageProps} />
                </Grid>
              </AnimatePresence>
              <Footer />
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </ThemeProvider>
      </UIProvider>
    </Provider>
  )
}
export default MyApp
```

My UIContext.tsx file:

```
import React, { createContext, FC, SetStateAction, useContext, useState } from 'react'

export type UIContextType = {
  menuPanelOpen: boolean
  setMenuPanelOpen: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<boolean>>
  navbarOpen: boolean
  setNavbarOpen: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<boolean>>
  loggedIn: boolean
}

const defaultValues: UIContextType = {
  menuPanelOpen: true,
  setMenuPanelOpen: (): void => {},
  navbarOpen: true,
  setNavbarOpen: (): void => {},
  loggedIn: false
}
export const UIContext = createContext<UIContextType>(defaultValues)

export function useUIContext() {
  return useContext(UIContext)
}

export const UIProvider: FC = ({children: children}) =>  {
  const [menuPanelOpen, setMenuPanelOpen] = useState(defaultValues.menuPanelOpen)
  const [navbarOpen, setNavbarOpen] = useState(defaultValues.navbarOpen)
  const [loggedIn, setLoggedIn] = useState(defaultValues.loggedIn)

  const value: UIContextType = {
    menuPanelOpen,
    setMenuPanelOpen,
    navbarOpen,
    setNavbarOpen,
    loggedIn
  }

  return (
    <UIContext.Provider value={value}>
      { children }
    </UIContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

A component that uses the setter:

```
import { Grid, Typography } from '@material-ui/core'
import { makeStyles, createStyles } from '@material-ui/styles'
import LoginSignupForm from "../components/LoginSignupForm"
import { useEffect, useLayoutEffect } from 'react'
import { useUIContext } from '../contexts/UIContext'

const theme = makeStyles( theme =>
  createStyles({
    form: {

    },
    sidePane: {
      backgroundColor: "#333333",
      padding: '2rem',
      color: "#ffffff",

      '&::before': {
        content: '',
      }
    }
  })
) 

export default function SignupTest(props: any) {
  const { menuPanelOpen, setMenuPanelOpen, loggedIn } = useUIContext()
  const styles = theme()

  useEffect(() => {
    setMenuPanelOpen(false)
    console.log("menuPanelOpen is now ", menuPanelOpen)
  }, [])
  
  return (
    <Grid container item>
    <Grid container item xs={12} md={4} flexDirection="column" className={styles.sidePane}>
      <Grid item><Typography variant="h3"><b>TEST</b></Typography></Grid>
      <Grid container item flexDirection="column" justifyContent="center" flexGrow={1}><Typography variant="h4" textAlign="center"><b>TEST 1 2 3</b></Typography></Grid>
    </Grid>
    <Grid container item className={styles.form} xs={12} md={8} flexDirection="column" justifyContent="center" alignItems="center">
      <LoginSignupForm />
    </Grid>
  </Grid>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that

`useUIContext()` is on the same level of `<UIProvide />`
So at the moment of initialization, it refers to a separated context that does not exist,

instead of the `context` inside `<UIProvider />` you are looking for.

```
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  const { menuPanelOpen, setMenuPanelOpen, navbarOpen, setNavbarOpen } = useUIContext()

  return(
      <UIProvider>
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <Grid container flexDirection="column">
          <Grid container item flexWrap="nowrap">
            { menuPanelOpen && <MenuPanel /> }
            <Grid container item flexDirection="column" sx={{minHeight: '100vh'}}>
              { navbarOpen && <NavBar isMobile={isMobile} /> }
              <AnimatePresence exitBeforeEnter>
                <Grid container item justifyContent="center" flexGrow={1} component={motion.div} key={router.pathname} initial={{opacity: 0, y: 20}} animate={{opacity: 1, y: 0}} exit={{opacity: 0, y: -20}}>
                  <Component {...pageProps} />
                </Grid>
              </AnimatePresence>
              <Footer />
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </ThemeProvider>
      </UIProvider>
  )
}
export default MyApp
```

So what it means is that you might want to do something like

```
function MyApp(props: AppProps) {

return (
 <UIProvide>
    <AppWithoutProvider {...props}/>
 </UIProvide>
)
}

function AppWithoutProvide({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
const { menuPanelOpen, setMenuPanelOpen, navbarOpen, setNavbarOpen } = useUIContext()
return (
           <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
            <Grid container flexDirection="column">
              <Grid container item flexWrap="nowrap">
                { menuPanelOpen && <MenuPanel /> }
                <Grid container item flexDirection="column" sx={{minHeight: '100vh'}}>
                  { navbarOpen && <NavBar isMobile={isMobile} /> }
                  <AnimatePresence exitBeforeEnter>
                    <Grid container item justifyContent="center" flexGrow={1} component={motion.div} key={router.pathname} initial={{opacity: 0, y: 20}} animate={{opacity: 1, y: 0}} exit={{opacity: 0, y: -20}}>
                      <Component {...pageProps} />
                    </Grid>
                  </AnimatePresence>
                  <Footer />
                </Grid>
              </Grid>
            </Grid>
          </ThemeProvider>
)
}
```

The format is ugly and I skipped all the unrelated code but you should be able to get the idea.

Comment: It's being brought in as <UIProvider>.

Comment: So I don't wrap _app at all and just call it from the context just like the child components?

Comment: @JoelHager I think you should call useContext inside the <UIProvider />. Because you call `useUIContext()` at the same level of <UIProvider/> , it's probably becoming a separated parent context at the moment of initialization, so it's never the children one you are looking for. You still wrap your _app but `initialize` and call `useContext` truly inside the <UIProvider /> as my solution advised.

Comment: The useUiContext returns a context

Comment: @JoelHager the context might be just another context with default value. For debug purpose, you can pass your default as `createContext({})`. Then call useContext inside the provider and `useEffect(()=>{}, [context])` to check if the context is changing to your first value. If no, there is something wrong with your code.